# How to call Senecajs action from .Net using Rabbitmq

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, seneca

I have a microservices system using RabbitMq as Message Broker, I want to talk with them from .Net. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/ as nodejs client and the official .NET client https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html

I'd suggest to read: https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html there are several examples